# Json Views template not found when run as a war file

Tags: grails, deployment, embedded-tomcat-8

I am using Json views plugin of grails. Which works in development, but when I run it as a jar file, it is not able to find the templates/gson files for rendering. I get the following error

```
//code 
    def template = jsonViewTemplateEngine.resolveTemplate(<path to template>)
            def writable = template.make(kase: kase)

//exception
    Cannot invoke method make() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method make() on null object
```

Json Views we are using are a part of a inline plugin we are developing. Jar we create also runs with that inline plugin (implemented using gradle wrapper)

Any ideas/suggestions?

**Environment:**
Grails - 3.2.0
Groovy - 2.4.7
Json-Views plugin - 1.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Views are pre-compiled into classes for deployment via Gradle and the `compileGsonViews` task. This is done using the `project.name` setting by default.

You will notice in the `build/main/gson-classes` directory the classes that are produced. For example if your application name is `foo` you will have classes like `foo_book_show_gson.class` where the `foo_` part is considered the "package" name.

At runtime. The package name to use to resolve views calculated from the `info.app.name` setting in `grails-app/conf/application.yml`.

What this means is that if in Gradle your `project.name` evaluates to `foo` and the setting in `application.yml` is also `foo` then all is well. This is the most common case as typically your application name is the same in both places.

If `info.app.name` and the Gradle `project.name` don't match up you can get the problem where views don't resolve.

You have two options to fix this. One is to modify `build.gradle` to explicitly specify the package name:

```
 compileGsonViews.packageName = 'foo'
```

Then make sure `info.app.name` matches that value.

The second option is rename your project directory so that `info.app.name` and `project.name` align.

Answer (score 0):

Json View behavior is different in dev mode and war mode.

```
WritableScriptTemplate template
if (Environment.isDevelopmentEnvironmentAvailable()) {
    template = attemptResolvePath(path)
    if (template == null) {
        template = attemptResolveClass(path)
    }
} else {
    template = attemptResolveClass(path)
    if (template == null) {
        template = attemptResolvePath(path)
    }
}
if (template == null) {
    template = NULL_ENTRY
}
```

In development mode grails will load your template by file path first then load by class name.
If you are working on case insensitive file system,template file like 
'your_template_name' and 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME' will be treated same.
But class name is case sensitive,'your_template_name_class' and 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME_CLASS' is different;

Maybe your template file name is incorrect.

For example, if your classname is:

```
QueryResult
```

Your template file should located in:

```
/views/queryResult/_queryResult.gson
```

Json View will search class like:

```
<Project-Name>_queryResult__queryResult_gson
```