# Could not resolve view with name 'alive' when deployed with Tomcat 8

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

When deployed to our production server(AWS Linux, Tomcat 8, Grails 3.3.3, Java 1.8)  the app cannot find the view. When running locally (grails prod run-app, grails run-app, Java 1.8) there is no issue.

**View(alive.gson)**

```
import java.time.Instant
json{
   dateTime Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
   version config.getProperty("info.app.version", String, null)
}
```

**URL Mappings**

```
"/apistatus"(view:"alive")
```

**URLS**

http://localhost:8080/cf/apistatus (works without issue)
https://my.domain.com/cf/apistatus (throws exception - javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'alive' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet')

**Update**

I've configured the app according to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708115/json-views-template-not-found-when-run-as-a-war-file) which has not worked

Comment: Are you using Elastic beanstalk or tomcat on EC2 directly?
Can you access tomcat logs? catalina logs. Should have clue in that.

Comment: Tomcat on EC2. The exception is coming from the tomcat log. The page renders "HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'timestamp' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap' - maybe not public?" with an exception report. I believe the page is rendering a secondary error as Grails is using a default template since it cannot find the correct template.

Comment: verify your JDK version of local and that of EC2..

Comment: Try to log you values in gson, think that problem can be with they

Comment: @Koloritnij I cannot 'log' the values in gson as it cannot find the gson template

Comment: @srikanthNutigattu Java 1.8 for prod and local

Comment: Are you using the latest Tomcat 8, i.e., 8.5.32 or 8.0.53? I had a fun little bug in a Grails app caused by a bug in Tomcat itself.

Comment: @doelleri I am using Tomcat 8.0.50

Comment: @kuda I meaned to check values that they are not null in action..